# Can you increase the max size of Rich Text fields?

Tags: richtext

I'm unable to save an entry, and I'm getting an error saying that a Rich Text field is too long.

If I disable the entry, it saves fine, but when it's enabled, it doesn't save.

Can I increase the max size of a Rich Text field?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under your Rich Text field's setting, there is a "Column Type" option that's set to `text` by default, which will hold about 64k worth of data.  You can change it to `mediumtext`, which will store about 16M worth of data.

[image]